# Как игнорировать: hover стиль css на тачпадах?

Tags: html, css, jquery, css3, css-animation

```
    .background-box img {
    -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1.5s ease-in-out
}

.portfolio__item a:hover .background-box img,
.portfolio__item a:focus .background-box img,
.portfolio__item:active .background-box img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

При скролле тачпада на ноуте, начинаются лаги из-за того что эффект scale(1.1), имеет transition: transform 1.5s ease-in-out.

Как сделать так чтоб при скролле на таче :hover не срабатывал, только при перемещение курсора по этому блоку, а к переходу следующему снова не срабатывал при скролле, только как снова пошевелишь курсором

Ведь лаги сильно ощутимые и зависят от времени transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За мою практику я еще не нашел более адекватного решения, чем использовать скрипт для определения события . 
[Подробнее ...](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave)